# Driving 4 100mA motors using GPIO pins and BS170s

Tags: mosfet, motor, raspberry-pi, gpio

I'm trying to drive 4 tiny [vibrating motors](https://www.adafruit.com/products/1201) which draw 100mA at a maximum of 5V. I need to control them using PWM from the GPIO pins and would like to accomplish this in the smallest form-factor possible as it's for a portible device. I've looked at other motor driver hats and see that most require external power supplies which turns me off as all I want to use is the supply that is powering my RPi.

I've been asking some friends what they think and I've been advised to use 4 [BS170](https://www.fairchildsemi.com/datasheets/BS/BS170.pdf) MOSFETs each with a 1N4001 diode to protect against voltage in the wrong direction when turning off the motors.

I'm here essentially to verify that this is a good setup and hear other recommendations as I'm not super familiar with this level of hardware. I'd also love some help with diagramming out how I would go about wiring these (in regards to the MOSFET and diode) coming off the Pi.

Thanks for your help!

Comment: Why the RPi power supply can't be qualified as "external"? Why do you think your homebrew driver won't require it? Obviously you won't get enough current out of GPIO pins.

Comment: I'd be worried that the PCB traces cannot handle a 4 watt draw, and that your supply will brown out, or worse, ignite. Be sure that you're using a minimum 10 Watt 5V power supply, and more than that if you're using peripherals.

Comment: @EugeneSh. I know I won't get enough current - that's why I'm using the MOSFETs in the first place.

Comment: @KevinMurphy And the MOSFETs will take the current from where?

Comment: @EugeneSh. a 5V pin

Comment: Then why can't you power a driver from the same pin?

Comment: I can, just some of the hats i've seen use a variation of connections that require more accessories.

Comment: What are these hats you are talking about? Heatsinks?

Comment: Ah.. this is the jargon for a daughter board... Anyway, you really don't have to use a "HAT", but build a circuit with a driver on it yourself, exactly like you are planning with the mosfets

Comment: @tuskiomi thanks for bringing that up. something else for me to consider :D

Comment: @EugeneSh. yeah just something like this: https://www.adafruit.com/product/2348 is a bit overkill for my project. Just trying to get advice on the smallest / cost effective solution.

Comment: The BS170 may not give you the performance you want at 3.3V. Look for a device with a lower gate threshold voltage.

Answer (score 2):

If you have a little bit of leeway in what voltage the motors can take then one option is to use a [ULN2803A](http://www.ti.com/product/ULN2803A) to drive the motors directly. The device comes in a SOIC-18 package, and even includes flyback diodes in order to save as much board space as possible. Tying the drivers together in pairs will distribute the load across each, keeping the voltage drop low.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fzVdmt.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Comment: thanks for the recommendation. the opperating voltage is 2-5V (not sure if you saw that) but in terms of leeway, do you mean going over this? Since the ULN2803A is 8 channel, can I power all 4 motors with this one device?

Comment: The outputs do result in a small voltage drop. The motors have to be able to still operate even with this difference in voltage.

Answer (score 1):

The BS170 would work just fine with a loss of 0.5 volts maximum assuming worse case of 5 ohms RDSon.  The ULN2803 would work just fine driving 4 servos on at the same time. You will have a voltage drop of just over 1 volt in the ULN2803.  You can pick another MOSFET that has a UIS (Un Clamped Inductive Spike) rating and no external diode is needed or required. You can get several amps very cheaply in SMD (Surface Mount Device) package. All of the above parts are available in SMD  packages. I would recommend not powering them from the Raspberry pi board as this will induce noise on the board and in its ground circuits.

Comment: _"The BS170 would work just fine"_ - I wouldn't bet on that. Maximum threshold voltage is 3V, which is not much below the Pi's output voltage. Unfortunately I only have one sample to test, but it has a threshold of 2.02V (less than the 'typical' value of 2.1V) yet drops 0.75V at 100mA with 3.30V on the Gate.

Comment: I stand corrected, I was thinking of a different processor. I used the Fairchild data sheet, BS170/D and looked at the typical which is 1.5V. If you look at the On data sheet has higher numbers. It may or may not work so you gave the best answer. To be safe it is best to look at the data sheet for the part you have, not all data sheets are the same for the same part number.